# Bing translator widget without original text popup and show the translation button text automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bing

I used Bing Language converter in my website. It work successfully. But I need to disable annoying popups attached to hover event on translated texts that shows original text.

I used the below code in onComplete callback :

Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showHighlight = false;
Microsoft.Translator.Widget.domTranslator.showTooltips = false; 
But it did not work. I searched every where. But not get any solution. Please give me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use below style that will hide one div:
    #MSTCImprove   {
     display: none;
   }
and change ui=true to ui=false